# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar un proceso de RazorEngine que acumula memoria RAM en C# VisualStudio al convertir XML a PDF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml, razor, manejo-de-memoria

El propósito de mi proyecto es convertir facturas electrónicas de hacienda en PDF.
Dichas facturas están en formato XML, el programa lee la ruta que yo le dé y filtra los archivos que sean .xml, guardo sus rutas en un arreglo.

Luego con un foreach  recorro el arreglo enviando cada uno a un proceso void donde se realiza la conversión, al comenzar esta conversión primero se deserializa el XML y se convierte a un objeto siguiendo una clase dada por la documentación oficial de hacienda.

Teniendo ya el objeto lo envío a razor junto a su plantilla correspondiente. Adjunto línea de código:

```
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // El tipo o el miembro están obsoletos
                    resultHTML = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(sHTML, oComprobante);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // El tipo o el miembro están obsoletos
```

sHTML es la ruta de la plantilla y oComprobante vendría a ser el objeto ya deserializado/serializado.
Después de esto se escribe en una ruta el PDF y continúan las iteraciones.

El programa ya funciona y hace lo que debe hacer, el problema radica en que cada iteración va subiendo la memoria RAM, hice una prueba convirtiendo 5000 archivos y la memoria subió a rangos de 500-800mb, después de buscar cada proceso que pudiera aplicarle .Close(); y .Dispose(); seguía subiendo igual, me di cuenta que la línea de código mencionada arriba era la que iba acumulando memoria, ya que corrí el programa sin ejecutar esa línea y la memoria se mantuvo estable en 28mb, aún recorriendo el arreglo.

Por lo que acudo en su ayuda para saber como podría optimizar este proceso. Si requieren más código de mi proyecto háganmelo saber.

Comment: Al hacer parsing de los XML, posiblemente esté quedando algo instanciado que, por estar ahí dentro del método iterando entre archivos, no es liberado correctamente. No sé mayor cosa de C# pero sí creo que es relevante que indiques versiones de lo que estás usando, pues no se sabe si te topaste con cosas como [esta](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/180)

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder, mira te comento, el equipo donde estoy desarrollando no me ha dado ningún problema ya que supongo que la memoria está sobrada, la cosa es que la aplicación va dirigida a computadoras más austeras. Concuerdo contigo en al Parsear el razor deja algo abierto que se va acumulando, la verdad no tengo idea por donde empezar a revisar, ya que los métodos de Razor no son modificables ni nada por el estilo. Quiero pensar que debo cerrar algo desde mi Main program, mi versión de Razor es 3.10.0 y NetFramework 4.6.1 en consola